# Recycler View Keeps Adding 2 items at once and will overwrite previous items when new item added

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

essentially when any data is entered into the recycler view two objects are created on the recycler view that are the exact same and when new data is added the old data is overwritten and replaced yet even though I type something into the edit text for the todo title and add it two items get added. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if more code is required then please just ask and I will be able to provide it.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.todoit

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoViewModel: TodoViewModel



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)



        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val todo = Todo(0,todoTitle,false)
                    todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf(todo))
                    rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
                    etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                    insertDataToDataBase(todo)
                    todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
        }
        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }
    }}


    private fun insertDataToDataBase(todo: Todo) {
        val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(todoTitle)) {
            //Add data to database
            todoViewModel.addTodoToDataBase(todo)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }




    private fun inputCheck(todoTitle:String):Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(todoTitle))
    }
}
```

Todo Adapter

```
package com.example.todoit

import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_todo.view.*

class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos() {
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

Comment: The previous data is overwritten because you are creating & setting the adapter every time the button is clicked. Create & set the adapter in onCreate just once, then you can later add items to the adapter via the `addTodo `.

Answer (score 0):

So. Also you can change to

```
inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    
    fun show() {
        if(adapterPosition >= 0){
             val curTodo = todos[adapterPosition]
             // all of you want to do
        }                 
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.show()
}
```

from time to time holders are removed by adapter and get **adapterPosition = -1** 
If you something changed in your item you shold to call **notifyItemChanged(position)**

And. Recycler can create more than two holders. If your views have height as 0dp Recycler will create holders for all your list. And if you put Recycler in ConstraintLayout it also will be true. I recomend use RelativeLayout for it.